# The subspace topology of an initial topology

Tags: general-topology

Given a set $X$ and an indexed family $(Y_{i}, \tau_i)_{i \in I}$ of topological spaces with functions $f_{i}: X \rightarrow Y_{i}$. The [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology#Definition) $\tau$ on $X$ induced by the collection $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is the *coarsest* topology on $X$ such that each
$$
f_{i}:(X, \tau) \to (Y_{i}, \tau_i)
$$
is continuous. It follows that $\{f_i^{-1} (O_i) \mid i\in I, O_i \in \tau_i\}$ is a [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Definition) of $\tau$.

Now let $X' \subset X$ and $f_i'$ be the restriction of $f_i$ to $X'$. Let $\tau'$ be the initial topology on $X'$ induced by the collection $(f'_i)_{i\in I}$. For $i\in I, O_i \in \tau_i$, we have
$$
(f'_i)^{-1} (O_i) = X' \cap f_i^{-1} (O_i).
$$

As such, $\tau'$ coincides with the subspace topology that $\tau$ induces on $X'$.

> Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. In fact, it is a special case of transitivity of initial topology. We take the initial topology on $X$ induced by maps $(f_i: X \to Y_i)_{i ∈ I}$, where every $Y_i$ has the initial topology induced by maps $(g_{i, j}: Y_i \to Z_{i, j})_{j ∈ J_i}$. The topology on $X$ is the same as the initial topology induced by the family $(g_{i, j} ∘ f_i)_{j ∈ J_i, i ∈ I}$. Note that the topology of a subspace is the initial topology induced by the inclusion.